# log in system with sessions and mysqli done something wrong

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello guys I am trying to make a simple log-in system for a school project, I got it to work when I didn't implement the database. But as you can see now that I tried to implement the database it don't work so well since I can't make the PHP tags at the start and end of the echo's, anyway anyone who can help me out? 
As I said it worked when I just wrote a random username and password, and didn't have any database thing on it.

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    include('../inc/dbconnection_inc.php');
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconnection, 'SELECT * FROM users');
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $p=$_POST['password'];
    $u=$_POST['username'];

    if ($u==echo $row["username"] AND $p==echo $row["password"]);
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = echo $row["username"];
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
```

Comment: What is `$u==echo $row["username"]` supposed to do?

Comment: It is to tell it that if the username and password you type in is on the database, you should be able to log in.

Comment: Instead of calling the entire table and selecting it, why don't you search the table with the username and password with the WHERE command. If it returns with zero results, then you know you can't authenticate them.

Comment: Well actully the table is only 3 things, id, username and password. I think my issue is with the php tags or something I'm not sure...

Comment: Does it have something to do with ob_start and ob_end_flush (); that should be implemented?

Comment: Firstly, don't use `AND` use `&&` because it has precedence over `AND`. Second, remove the semi-colon in `if ($u==echo $row["username"] AND $p==echo $row["password"]);` which is most likely the issue here. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which will signal any errors found. Plus, don't store passwords in plain text, use a more secure method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you need `echo` there. According to the manual, echo returns nothing.

Try removing all `echo`'s from the code, like

```
...
if ($u === $row["username"] && $p === $row["password"])
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

(also I usually use `&&` instead of `AND`, that also could be the cause)

Besides your code will check only first fetched row (I think you're aware of that?)

Comment: Thank you so much Actine, you totally made my day it worked! :D you are awesome, also to the other guys thanks for helping as well

Comment: Well when you say check only first fetched row, what do you mean exactly? that if I had more members it wouldn't be able to find them?

Comment: @MagicRabbit heh, thanks. Actually I see that the same answers were given by commenters to the original post while I was typing, so some credit for them too. `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns only one row (the next row from result), if I'm not mistaken. So to check all users you'll have to use `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {...}`. Also limiting a query to just one row with WHERE, as suggested by others, is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p=$_POST['password'];
$u=$_POST['username'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
if($result=mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query)){

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $u);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($u == $row["username"] && $p == $row["password"]);
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = echo $row["username"];
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
}else{
    //fail
}
```

- Remove the echo
- Select a specific user by adding a Where Clasuse
- Prepare  your statment

Comment: the issue with this is that if I made more then one user saying WHERE "something" would narrow it down, and I would only be able to use one unless I gave a specific group of users a colon in my database with the text admin, and then write WHERE id admin.  Or something like that.

Comment: @MagicRabbit I am not sure what you mean, If you want to check if a user exist in the table you will need to add a WHERE.Maybe it works for you right now because you have only one record.

Comment: Yeah I kind'a get what you mean... I'm just not sure how to really fix it cause I believe I would have to make a $id=$GET_["id"]; or something somewhere first right? or am i stupid? :D

Comment: @MagicRabbit you should be able to use `username` since that should be unique in your table

Comment: @MagicRabbit If username is unique (otherwise what's the point? it is supposed to be an identifier, right?), then `select * from users where username = ?` would work: it will either return 1 or 0 results, and if there's one result, you just check the password. Moreover if you don't hash passwords in the database (given that it's an experimental project, because otherwise you absolutely must), you can include it in query too: `select * from users where username = ? and password = ?`